# VF Page to Show Related Lists from Lookup Object on my Main Object

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I am trying to develop a small VF page that will eventually be added to the standard SF page for a custom object called `Test_Site__c`.

`Test_Site__c` contains a lookup relationship to an object called `ELTON__Other__c`.

I wrote the following VF page and it works fine.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Test_Site__c">
  <p>Site {! Test_Site__c.Description__c }.</p> 
  <p>Other {! Test_Site__c.ELTON_Other__r.Name }.</p> 
</apex:page>
```

That displays a certain Test Site with it's associated ELTON Other name. That makes me think that I have the 2 objects correctly related.

And if I take `Test_Site__c` out of the equation I can write the page that I want for the lookup `ELTON__Other__c` object...

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="ELTON__Other__c"> 
  <p>Other {! ELTON__Other__c.Name }.</p> 
  <apex:relatedList list="ELTON__Equipment__r"/>
  <apex:relatedList list="ELTON__Equipment_Assignments__r"/>
  <apex:relatedList list="ELTON__Equipment1__r"/> 
  <apex:relatedList list="ELTON__Equipment_Loans__r"/>  
</apex:page>
```

That too works wonderfully in that it displays 4 related lists for an `ELTON__Other__c` object

Since a `Test_Site__c` record only ever has either 0 or 1 `ELTON__Other__c` records related to it I would like to display the 4 related lists from `ELTON_Other__c` and display them on the related `Test_Site__c` page (so meaning add the lists to the tiny first page example above).

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance for any insight you could provide :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For that just use a `subject` parameter of the `apex:relatedList` tag:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Test_Site__c">

    <p>Site {!Test_Site__c.Description__c }.</p> 
    <p>Other {!Test_Site__c.ELTON_Other__r.Name }.</p> 

    <apex:relatedList subject="{!Test_Site__c.ELTON_Other__c}" list="ELTON__Equipment1__r"/> 

</apex:page>
```