# Related Fields not available on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, related-list

I have a long list of "related lists" available to me that I can put on a Contact layout. I would like to display these same related lists on a visualforce page using `<apex:relatedList>` and the Contact standard controller...however, I'm not able to do this because they are not lookup fields, and I cannot find the child relationship names.

Does that mean that I'm not able to use them with `<apex:relatedList>`?

Comment: Can you give an example of one of these related lists you are unable to display?

Comment: One of them relates to a custom object "Proposal__c". Another is a field on "Property__c", "Primary_Contact__c"--looks like Property(Primary Contact). Another is "Notes & Attachments". None of these are from Lookup fields, but they are all available as related lists.

Comment: I do not know if you'll be able to get Notes & Attachments, but you should definitely be able to get the other relationships. Both Lookup and Master Detail relationships can be shown with apex:relatedList, and you can get the relationship name from them by looking at the field detail.

Comment: Is something wrong with my visualforce then? 

`<apex:page standardController="Contact" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >

    <apex:relatedList list="Proposals" />


    
</apex:page>`

Comment: `Content cannot be displayed: 'Proposals' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Contact`

Comment: "Proposals" is not a lookup field on contacts. But, it's still available on the contacts layout as a related list. I found the contacts lookup field on Proposals objects and used that related list name, and this does not seem to work.

Comment: You're going to need to go to the field detail for the relationship (that relationship field is going to be on the Proposal, not the Contact!) which will show you the relationship name. It's probably `proposals__r` unless whoever made it was in a weird mood.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
[VF Page to Show Related Lists from Lookup Object on my Main Object](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8177/vf-page-to-show-related-lists-from-lookup-object-on-my-main-object?rq=1)

The problem was that I needed to add an __r to the end of the "child relationship name". 
New Apex:
PROPOSAL

```
<apex:relatedList title="" subject="{!Contact}" list="Proposals__r" />
```

PROPERTY(PRIMARY CONTACT)

```
<apex:relatedList title="" subject="{!Contact}" list="Properties1__r" />
```

Comment: that is already mentioned in many documents :)